# How to configure facebook sign up functionality in android/ios app

Tags: php, android, ios, facebook

Can I configure sign up using face book in my android/ios app? 
I have successfully integrate Facebook Login in ios and android but this time I need to use face book sign up. I have gone through google and found some tutorial but I got it for web site using iframe. 
I also need to store user email and password in my server side database at time of Facebook sign up. 
I am using php/mysql at server side. 
Thanks in advance to spend your valuable time to solve my question. 
Regards, Mayur.

Comment: You can always use `Fb-Login data` to store in your database tht'z one way to automatically signing up the user.

Comment: you can create a webview and call the URL : http://m.facebook.com/r.php for registration and once registration success you can alert user as per landing page. But i dont think you can store User Email and password. Rather you can get their data while login with facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want registration via Facebook in your app.

for **iOS**,

What I have used to get information of user from Facebook login is

1) Show facebook dialog for login into facebook account.

2) When successfully login in `- (void) dialogDidSucceed:(NSURL*)url` method will call of `FBLoginDialog.m` file

3) Now use `FbGraphResponse` to get user details to fullfil your registration process.

Example :

```
-(void)getUserDetails 
{
NSMutableDictionary * params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] autorelease];
            [params setValue:@"normal" forKey:@"type"];
            fb_graph_response =[[FBRequestWrapper defaultManager] doGraphGet:@"me" withGetVars:params];
            NSLog(@"getMeButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
responseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            responseArray = [fb_graph_response.htmlResponse JSONValue];

            userdetails = [[Userdetails alloc] init];

            [userdetails setUserid:[responseArray valueForKey:@"id"]];
            [userdetails setUsername:[responseArray valueForKey:@"name"]];
            [userdetails setGender:[responseArray valueForKey:@"gender"]];
            [userdetails setHometown:[[responseArray valueForKey:@"hometown"] valueForKey:@"name"]];
            [userdetails setLocation:[[responseArray valueForKey:@"location"]valueForKey:@"name"]];
            [userdetails setBio:[responseArray valueForKey:@"bio"]];
            [userdetails setFirst_name:[responseArray valueForKey:@"first_name"]];
            [userdetails setLast_name:[responseArray valueForKey:@"last_name"]];
            if ([[responseArray valueForKey:@"email"] length]>0)
            {
                NSString * email = [responseArray valueForKey:@"email"] ;
                email = [email stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u0040" withString:@"@"];
                [userdetails setEmail:email];
                email = nil;
            }
 [self doRegistrationToAppWithEmail:userdetails.email AndFacebookID:userdetails.userid AndUserName:userdetails.username];
 }
```

Now you can have user details of user for registration process. Show these info in registration view and make it editable so user can change it.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: okay I will use this data and make it editable in my ios device.